# Resetting checkboxes from updating drop down box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I am trying to disable the checkbox based on the select value in Jquery. For an example, if the user selects 1 it hides checkbox 1 so on.

A problem I am running into is that I can't get the checkbox to reset after the user selects a new option since the disabled checked box can get submitted as a value even though its disabled?

**HTML:**

```
<tr><th><label for="dropdown">Dropdown:</label></th><td><select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>

</select></td></tr>

<li><label for="id_checkbox_0"><input id="id_checkbox_0" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 1</label></li>
<li><label for="id_checkbox_1"><input id="id_checkbox_1" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" /> 2</label></li>
<li><label for="id_checkbox_2"><input id="id_checkbox_2" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" /> 3</label></li>
<li><label for="id_checkbox_3"><input id="id_checkbox_3" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" /> 4</label></li>
```

**Jquery Mobile:**

```
 $("#dropdown").change(function() {
     //$('input:(#id_checkbox')').removeAttr('checked');
     var index = $(':selected', this).index();
     $('#id_checkbox_'+index).attr("disabled", true);
     $('#id_checkbox_'+index).attr('checked', false);
     $('input:not(#id_checkbox_'+index+')').attr("disabled", false);
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/5oedargs/9/

Comment: "*since the `disabled` checked box can get submitted as a value even though its `disabled`?*" - no it can't (shouldn't), a `disabled` element is automatically considered 'unsuccessful,' and is not submitted. Reference: "[Forms in HTML documents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1)" (from W3.org).

Comment: Alright thanks for the info. Just need to uncheck the option that it disabled for user interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable, and re-enable, the checkboxes via changing the option, I'd suggest:

```
$('#dropdown').change(function () {
    var opt = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    $('li input[type="checkbox"]').prop('disabled', false).filter(function(){
        return opt.value === this.value;
    }).prop({
        'disabled' : true,
        'checked' : false
    });
});
```

```js
$('#dropdown').change(function () {
    var opt = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    $('li input[type="checkbox"]').prop('disabled', false).filter(function(){
        return opt.value === this.value;
    }).prop({
        'disabled' : true,
        'checked' : false
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <label for="dropdown">Dropdown:</label>
      </th>
      <td>
        <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="id_checkbox_0">
      <input id="id_checkbox_0" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="id_checkbox_1">
      <input id="id_checkbox_1" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" />2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="id_checkbox_2">
      <input id="id_checkbox_2" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" />3</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="id_checkbox_3">
      <input id="id_checkbox_3" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" />4</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or, more concisely:

```
$('#dropdown').change(function () {
    var opt = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    $('li input[type="checkbox"]').prop('disabled', function() {
        var test = this.value === opt.value;
        if (test) {
            this.checked = false;
        }
        return test;
    });
});
```

```js
$('#dropdown').change(function () {
    var opt = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    $('li input[type="checkbox"]').prop('disabled', function() {
        var test = this.value === opt.value;
        if (test) {
            this.checked = false;
        }
        return test;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <label for="dropdown">Dropdown:</label>
      </th>
      <td>
        <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="id_checkbox_0">
      <input id="id_checkbox_0" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="id_checkbox_1">
      <input id="id_checkbox_1" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" />2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="id_checkbox_2">
      <input id="id_checkbox_2" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" />3</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="id_checkbox_3">
      <input id="id_checkbox_3" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" />4</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And a slightly improved answer, that re-checks the checkbox if it was disabled, and unchecked, after being checked by the user:

```
$('li input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
    this.userChecked = this.checked;
});

$('#dropdown').on('change', function(){
    var opt = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    $('li input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
        'disabled' : function () {
            return opt.value === this.value;
        },
        'checked' : function () {
            var test = opt.value === this.value;
            if (test) {
                return false
            }
            else if (!test && this.userChecked) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```js
$('li input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){
    this.userChecked = this.checked;
});

$('#dropdown').on('change', function(){
    var opt = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    $('li input[type="checkbox"]').prop({
        'disabled' : function () {
            return opt.value === this.value;
        },
        'checked' : function () {
            var test = opt.value === this.value;
            if (test) {
                return false
            }
            else if (!test && this.userChecked) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <label for="dropdown">Dropdown:</label>
      </th>
      <td>
        <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="id_checkbox_0">
      <input id="id_checkbox_0" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />1</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="id_checkbox_1">
      <input id="id_checkbox_1" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" />2</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="id_checkbox_2">
      <input id="id_checkbox_2" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" />3</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="id_checkbox_3">
      <input id="id_checkbox_3" name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" />4</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jQuery.com/change/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jQuery.com/filter/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jQuery.com/prop/).

Comment: The disable checkbox does not work with Jquery Mobile.

Comment: It doesn't work with that library you *never mentioned* you were using in either your post, or in your tags?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what do you want, but to hide you should use jquery hide http://api.jquery.com/hide/
 or the html *display* attribute. To enable or disable try using:

`$('#id_checkbox_'+index).attr("disabled", "disabled");` instead of 'true' and 
`$('input:not(#id_checkbox_'+index+')').attr("disabled", "enabled");` instead of 'false'

Comment: the thing is hiding the checkbox still let the hidden checkbox get submitted?

Comment: probably yes if the attribute 'checked' is on it. But It seems not work with jquery mobile like you set up on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.checkboxradio()` method to check/uncheck and enable/disable.

```
/* check */
$(".selector").prop("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh");

/* uncheck */
$(".selector").prop("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh");

/* enable */
$(".selector").checkboxradio("enable");

/* disable */
$(".selector").checkboxradio("disable");
```